# Check if input contains some value from database table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I do not know if I made myself clear in the title but I will explain again. I have the input where I will paste one string, so I want to check if contains some string:

```
var str1 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
var str2 = "DEFG";

if(str1.indexOf(str2) != -1){
    alert(str2 + " found int the input!");
}
```

but this way I have to pre define the str2, when what I need is to compare with table values, imagine I have a table:

- (id=1 | desc="banana apple orange" | name="fruits").
- (id=2 | desc="batman superman finn" | name="heroes").

So now I paste the string and ajax goes into database returning the raws:

```
var str1 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
var str2 = dataFromTable;

if(str1.indexOf(desc) != -1){
    alert("This is a " + name);
}
```

So any help would be great, does not need to be exaclty like that, only need to compaire value FROM database and return something. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Return `data` in Json format and loop through it using `map` and compare your strings :

```
var data = [{id: 1, desc: "banana apple orange", name: 'fruits'},{id: 2, desc: "batman superman finn", name: 'heroes'}];
var str1 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";

data .map(function(obj) { 
    if(str1.indexOf(obj.desc) != -1){
         alert("This is a " + obj.name);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It really help, work fine with that code, but it reads only one word from the string, since you have 2 or more it ignores, I wonder if I could get something like "if str1 is equal ou similar to one of these words in the desc". I am trying to fill a array with the desc so I could compares with all index but it is too advanced to me.

Comment: Please try to add an example of this to your OP so I can well understand your desired output.